# how to get data from any specific page like blog page etc

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress website and there are some page like aboutpage, blogpage, contactpage etc,
so my concern is that i want data like title, paragraph from that specific page (blogpage)
so how do i get this for better understanding i add some reference image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIA7D.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1ZAB.png)

how do i get title and content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you refer this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

'42' is post id you can get all like title, content, ...

```
$post   = get_post( 42 );
$output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
print_r($post);
```